# A self-referential riddle

Tags: riddle

> I comprise a fixed number of lines
>   And that number is smaller than nine
>   As I self-referentially
>   Describe myself, potentially
>   I'll become a real breeze to divine
>
> **Who am I?**

This one isn't going to win any awards for Most Difficult Riddle of the Year, but it seemed amusing enough for a Sunday afternoon.

P.S. The answer is *not* "riddle".

**Edit: Watch out for spoilers in the comments below.**

**Edit 2:** by popular demand, I changed one word in the riddle to make it more accurate and pretty (though somewhat easier as a result).

Comment: This is not a limerick (as per the accepted answer) - it doesn't follow the rhyming pattern (AABBA).

Comment: i guess first line doesn't rhyme

Comment: @jhabbott It's not the world's best limerick, but I'd say it's a limerick. Btw I considered ending the first line with "lines" instead of "units", which would have made it a better limerick, but thought this would make it a poorer (too easy) riddle. So it's still possible to change it in such a way if that makes you happy.

Comment: you definitely need line(s) - also the fourth line is too long. Perhaps "continue, potentially" would scan better? After all "Describe myself" is already covered by "self-referentially"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> A limerick.
>
>   It has five lines (less than 9), and the riddle itself is a limerick.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> 1

I comprise a fixed number of units

> Kinda stuck here. Maybe there is only one unit?

And that number is smaller than nine

> 1 < 9 = True

As I self-referentially

> I am the ***one*** and only, 1

Describe myself, potentially

> Same as above, I am the ***one*** and only

I'll become a real breeze to divine

> Becoming the one and only in something or the number one in something will lead to lots of fame and very god-like status

Comment: Nice attempt, and it's a pretty good fit except for "self-referentially", which means something very specific (for example if the answer were "riddle", that would be an example of self-reference, but that wouldn't fit the first clue and to avoid trouble I specifically ruled it out). So no, it's not that.

Comment: For "fixed number of units", *unit* = 1.